# Pillow issue : writing on the same image -> save image with random name for each model

Tags: python, django

I got a question. Is it possible to save an image with an other and unique name from one image.

I got a default image, which is located into `invitation/defaut.png`.

I'm using a form with only one field dedicated to `nom`

I'd like to get save this image, with the writing of nom, with different name.

for example:

if name louis => defaut_randomletters.png

if name mike => defaut_randomletters.png

The issue I'm facing is that all the writing are save on the same image.

```
class Invitation(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='invitation_user')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='invitation/', default='invitation/defaut.png')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, editable=False, unique=True)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = self.nom
            
            super(Invitation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        #self.image.path = self.image.path.rsplit("/", 1)[0] + "/defaut_randomletters.png"
        img = Image.open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, self.image.path))
        #img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
        path_to_media_popstick = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'media/font/gillsans.ttf')
        path_to_media_emo = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'media/font/Symbola.ttf')
        #fnt = ImageFont.truetype(path_to_media_emo, 50)
        fnt = ImageFont.truetype(path_to_media_emo, size=50, layout_engine=ImageFont.LAYOUT_RAQM)
        font = ImageFont.truetype(path_to_media_popstick, 200)
        draw.text((50, 200),self.nom,(255,255,255),font=font)
        
        img.save(self.image.path + secrets.token_urlsafe(12) + ".png")
        
        super(Invitation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**EDIT :**

I've tried multiple way. Thanks to this way I can create a new image with new name (`img.save(self.image.path + secrets.token_urlsafe(12) + ".png"`). It saves correctly on the right folder but this is not related to the model.

For instance if I create Nico, this will create a new image defaut.pnggIZ29GUoOPVF6Q4e.png -> but on the model I'll have:

Image Actuellement: invitation/defaut.png (**defaut.pnggIZ29GUoOPVF6Q4e.png** is not linked to the model I just created)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are writing the image to the same path `self.image.path`. Update the file name part of the path, like

```
self.image.path = self.image.path.rsplit("/", 1)[0] + "/defaut_randomletters.png"
```

And `save()` the updated `self.image.path` to the database too.

Comment: Right before `img.save()`. Also, you probably want to use the disk path with `os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_DIR, self.image.path)` when reading and writing the image file.

Comment: I've tried this but it does not create the image. I've updated my post, I hope this will be clearer :) Thanks for your help

Comment: You have to set `self.image.path` to the new file path. `self.image.path = self.image.path + secrets.token_urlsafe(12) + ".png"` and then save the model `super(Invitation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: Could you please rewrite the code with your correction because I'm always getting an issue. Right now it's can't set attribute. If you don't mind I'll be really happy

Comment: The image is well created, with the writing but it's not linked to the model